# Automorphism group of tensor product of two graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-groups, automorphisms

Is there any relation between the automorphism group of the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) of two graphs $G = G_1 \times G_2$ and the automorphism groups of $G_1$ and $G_2$?

I am aware of the nice results for the Cartesian product of graphs.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817467/automorphisms-groups-of-direct-product-of-graphs

Comment: This product is called a few different things, in particular direct product as well as tensor product.

Answer (score 0):

In the handbook of product graphs by R.Hammack, W.Imrich and S. Klavsar there is the following theorem:
Let $\phi$ be an automorphism of a connected, non bipartite, R-thin graph $G$ with prime factorization $G= G_1 \times \dots \times G_k$. Then there exists a permutation $\pi$ of $\{1, \dots ,k\}$ together with isomorphisms $\phi_i: G_{\pi(i)}\rightarrow G_i$ such that $\phi (x_1, \dots, x_k)= (\phi_1(x_{\pi(1)}), \dots, \phi_k(x_{\pi(k)})$.